# Adding custom information to Python stack trace to be printed out

Tags: python

I am writing an interpreter for my simple programing language in Python. When there is an error during interpreting, a Python exception is thrown. The problem is that the stack trace is really ugly because it contains many recursive calls as I am navigating program's structure and interpreting it. And from the stack trace you cannot really see where in my program's structure the code was when it failed.

I know that I could capture all exceptions myself and rethrow a new exception adding some information about where an exception happened, but because it is recursive, I would have to do such rethrowing again and again.

I wonder if there isn't an easier way. For example, that next to path, line numbers, and function name in interpreter's code, I could print out also information where in the interpreted program's code that function is at that moment in the stack.

Answer (score 0):

You can write a `sys.excepthook` that prints whatever traceback you want.  I regularly use such a hook that uses the `traceback` module to print a normal traceback but with added lines that give the values of interesting local variables (via `f_locals` introspection).

Comment: So I am making this as a package. I am not sure if I would like to globally override `sys.excepthook`?

Comment: @Mitar: Certainly you should do so only when your client asks for it.  And you could provide a function to produce such a traceback manually from an exception thrown by your interpreter routine.